# Canvas does not show as expected

Tags: python, canvas

I'm a newbie to coding, so I assume this is simply a logic error on my end, so forgive me for my inabilities. I am intending for an initial canvas to appear to act as a sort of splash screen for my program, but rather than appearing, the canvas does not show at all, and simply stays invisible until the second canvas is called (after 4 seconds).

```
root = tk.Tk()
loadScreen = tk.Canvas(root, height = 700, width = 700, bg = "Black")
loadImage = PhotoImage(file="LoadScreen.gif")
load = loadScreen.create_image(2, 2, anchor = NW, image=loadImage)
loadScreen.pack()
root.after(4000, loadScreen.pack_forget())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would call `mainloop()` to make sure your windows are updating.

Internally, `mainloop()` calls

```
tk.update_idletasks()
tk.update()
```

I think you can use these to show the window.

Comment: This certainly fixed the main problem, but now the second canvas refuses to show, I have tried using `mainloop()` again in order to update the canvases, but to no avail. Could it be a result of me using the same root for both canvases?

Comment: `Mainloop()` will block, i.e. nothing else runs after that call. Don't call `mainloop()`. Call the other two methods instead,